# Custom UserControls in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, native

In Native C++, how do you add a usercontrol like in vb .net where you do form.controls.add(controls)

Because for instance, what if I wanted to make a usercontrol class that inherits from panel? How is this done in c++
Thanks

Comment: "Native C++"?   Do you mean standard C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes) for native C++ development. MFC is the original framework for Windows applications, long before .NET.